Keep getting positional argument follows keyword argument in yfinance?
For some reason I keep getting an odd positional argument follow keyword argument in yfinance?
#imports
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import time
from datetime import datetime
#setup
today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#code
#date formant 'yyyy-mm-dd'
print("Please input start and end in formant", today)
time.sleep(1)
stonks_df = yf.download('AMZN',
              print("Input start date:"),
              start=input(),
              print("Input end date:"),
              end=input(),
              group_by='column',
              progress=True)
stonks_df.head()
print(stonks)

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Commas separate arguments, not statements. You shouldn't be adding print statements in the middle of your download call; it makes the print statements get parsed as positional arguments.

The issue with your function call is that you are, as the error suggests, passing in positional argument after a keyword argument - which is what you did after you passed in the start keyword argument.
So, in Python:
func(arg1, arg2, kwarg1='text', kwarg2=123)  # this is OK

func(kwarg1='text', kwarg2=123)  # this is OK

func(arg1, kwarg1='text', arg2, kwarg2=123)  # this is NOT OK

I think this is what you want to do
stonks_df = yf.download('AMZN',
              start=input("Input start date:"),
              end=input("Input end date:"),
              group_by='column',
              progress=True)


I don't see a difference, I put them in DiffChecker and they're exactly the same?

Modified my answer for better clarity

Oh let me try that!

YES IT WORKED TYSM!
